# why core dumped error occurs with openmp (C language)

Tags: c, openmp

I'm a starter for openmp.
I wrote very very simple code like below.
when I compile that code and implement ./a.out, 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)' occurs. Why core dumped in this simple code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<omp.h>

int main(void){

    #pragma omp parallel
    {printf("thread num %d: first hello world!\n",omp_get_thread_num());
    printf("thread num %d; second hello world!\n",omp_get_thread_num());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you compiling this?

Comment: I just test your code and compile it using g++ -fopenmp filename.cpp -o executable and it run perfectly.